# Where I do find feature lists for upcoming Ubuntu versions? [16.04]

Tags: 16.04

I'm just wondering what I can look forward to in the next Ubuntu version.  In this case it's 16.04.

I also want to be able to speculate on what it's probably going to break and whether or not I should go through the hassle of writing some code that wont last more than a few months.

Where does one find an official feature list, or (as it appears to be) is there none?

Comment: On the site https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases you see a table of current, future and outdated releases of Ubuntu. The **Future** table currently only contains `16.04 Xenial Xerus` and links to its info page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus. You can probably find some information there as soon as the first Alpha version is out or after the FeatureFreeze...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia seems to have a rather extensive list of features, including the addition of Unity 8, and the possible transfer from Python 2 to Python 3. It probably isn't a very good idea to start preparing, however, as April is still 4 months away, and a lot could change in that time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29

Comment: By chance, do you know of the difference between Unity 7 and 8?  In particular, in the field of touch gestures?

Comment: Not sure. I only know that it's supposed to have a different theme.

Comment: That's the other thing I was thinking of doing, making a custom gtk3 one.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through [OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-download-new-features). It provides detailed list of all new features and explanation for the same.

Another one is [Ubuntu Official](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/20/canonical-unveils-6th-lts-release-of-ubuntu-with-16-04/), where in the best five new features of Ubuntu 16.06 are described in detail.

Then you also have [Wiki Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes), again all features with brief explanation